# Stripe API - stipe.setupIntents doesn't exist

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to delete **setup intent** via

```
stripe.setupIntents.delete
```

but that method doesn't exist. Any idea what am I doing wrong (I am looking at the official documents, **stripe.setupIntents** is what I need here).

I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <script>

        const stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}');

        const elements    = stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create('card', {
            hidePostalCode: true,
        });

        cardElement.mount('#card-element');

        const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
        const cardButton     = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret   = cardButton.dataset.secret;

        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {

            e.preventDefault()

            if (cardHolderName.value.length < 3) {
                $(cardHolderName).addClass('is-invalid')
                    .parent()
                    .append('<span class="text-danger">Please Insert Card Holder Name.</span>');
                return;
            } else {
                $(cardHolderName).removeClass('is-invalid');
                $(cardHolderName).next('.text-danger').remove();
            }

            let id  = $(cardButton).data('id')
            let url = $(cardButton).data('url')

            const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
                clientSecret, {
                    payment_method: {
                        card: cardElement,
                        billing_details: {
                            name: cardHolderName.value
                        }
                    }
                }
            )

            if (error) {

                let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = error.message;

            } else {

                let billingForm = $('#billing-form')

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        cardholder: billingForm.find('#cardholder').val(),
                        locum_organization: billingForm.find('#locum_organization').val(),
                        billing_addresses: billingForm.find('#billing_addresses').val(),
                        intent: setupIntent,
                        id: id
                    },
                    success: function(response) {

                    },
                    fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    },
                    error(response){

                        stripe.setupIntents.cancel(
                            setupIntent.id,
                            function(err, setupIntent) {
                                // asynchronously called
                            })
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only *cancel* a setup intent; not delete it. Also, setup intents can only be cancelled server-side. Right now it looks like you're trying to cancel it client-side with Stripe.js (which doesn't have a cancel setup intent method). It also isn't necessary to cancel a setup intent after it's gone through. In fact, you can't cancel a setup intent at all unless it's in one of these four processing states:

`requires_payment_method`, `requires_capture`, `requires_confirmation`, `requires_action`.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/cancel?lang=node

Your integration seems fine other than that. I would recommend leaving out the cancellation step entirely, and you should be good to go!